# PHP Mail client library

Tags: php, email, email-client

I know there is plenty of PHP mail libraries out there, but most of them are designed to *send* emails, is there any library that will help me *fetch* emails from imap/pop3 accounts, deal with attachments etc?

I'm already using `imap_*` functions from PHP IMAP extension but using it is problematic, as I have to re-invent the wheel in most cases (ie. parsing the result of `imap_fetchstructure` to get to attachments)

Mayby there is any ready to use lib build on top of `imap_*` or similar, that will help me deal with fetching mails, without re-writing all that logic behind well known problems?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have missed the obvious [`Zend_Mail`](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.mail.html) will do the trick

Answer (score 0):

Here is a PHP Pop3 Client that I use for a script on my server.

http://www.phpclasses.org/package/2-PHP-Access-to-e-mail-mailboxes-using-the-POP3-protocol.html

You could easily use that to create a graphical layout, but I have not had the necessity for it.

Comment: Thanks for hint, but that lib is little outdated (I haven't seen the `var` declarations in classes since a while now :) )