# PHP MySQL - Receive mail when data is inserted

Tags: php, mysql, database, email

Is it possible to receive and e-mail every time a customer, user, etc. fills in a form which is being inserted into tables on a MySQL Database?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes certainly, check out the mail() function:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php

Comment: Oh, thanks a lot! But, I might have typed my question wrong. I meant if it is possible for ME to receive and e-mail every time someone fills in a form. So, this "someone" won't receive a mail, but I will.

Comment: Use the mail() function to send to your address. Is that what you mean?

Comment: Just use your email in the `to` field of the function

Comment: Yes, exactly. It may not make a lot of sense for others than me, but its purpose is for me to keep track on the insert flow into the database.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  In the script that handles the form, eg, `<form method = "post" action = "someScript.php">` in "someScript.php", you can use the [mail](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php) function, which is easy enough as long as the e-mail isnt very complicated.  You will have to watch out for 
[header injection attacks](http://www.nyphp.org/PHundamentals/8_Preventing-Email-Header-Injection).

An alternative, and almost imperative if your understanding isn't that great, is to use an external PHP Library to handle sending the mail for you.  There's many out there, but [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1872639/good-php-email-library) and [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5874689/php-mail-client-library) have links to a couple.

Answer (score 0):

Right after your query you could simply call PHP's [mail() function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php)

A couple of links to get you started:

- [Introduction to sending email from PHP scripts](http://www.phphelp.com/article/article.php?art=2)
- [Sending e-mail with PHP](http://www.techrepublic.com/article/youve-got-php-sending-e-mail-with-php/1045471)
- [Finally always remember that Google is also our friend](https://www.google.com/search?q=php+send+mail)